# How often should ScyllaDB nodes be repaired?

Tags: scylla

Our organisation has move on from Cassandra to ScyllaDB recently and since there's so little info about ScyllaDB, and as the title suggests, how often should we repair ScyllaDB nodes to maintain equal count of rows in each node as Cassandra's repair frequency is recommended as 5 Days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scylla Manager automates the repair process and allows you to configure how and when repair occurs. When you create a cluster a repair task is automatically scheduled. **This task is set to occur each week by default,** but you can change it to another time, change its parameters or add additional repair tasks if needed.

Source: https://manager.docs.scylladb.com/stable/repair/index.html

[Edi: Pointing to latest docs]

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about Scylla Manager.